# Is there a consistent alternative to %in% in R?

Tags: r

R's `%in%` syntax is [sometimes presented](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html?q=%in%#logical-operators) as a shorthand for multiple statements checking for equality connected with a logical OR. But with regards to how R handels missing values, the behavior is inconsistent:

```r
month <- NA
month == 11 | month == 12
#> [1] NA
month %in% c(11, 12)
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

According to the help file, `%in%` is defined as `function(x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0`. Without specifying the `nomatch` argument, `match` would default to `nomatch = NA_integer_` and missing values would be "contagious" again. Is there another shorthand in R behaving like this? I would like to avoid redefining the function in each script I write.

The help file explains the current behavior with reference to if statements:

> That %in% never returns NA makes it particularly useful in if conditions.

I personally wouldn't mind adding an `is.na()` check in the condition and would even find it quite natural because it would be in line with other logical statements.

Comment: Where do you see the incosistency?

Comment: If you put it in a `data.table` you can use for example this: `dt[!is.na(month), test := month %in% c(11, 12)]` but for other cases I am not sure if there is an elegant way

Comment: @tmfmnk It seems that missing values are contagious in all logical conditions in R (meaning that the result will be a missing value as well) with the exception of `%in%`.

Comment: @dufei:  that's just not true about "all" logical conditions.  `NA | TRUE` is `TRUE`, and `NA & FALSE` is `FALSE`, with the same holding for the left-to-right versions `||` and `&&`.

Comment: How do you want to handle `NA %in% NA`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is anything in base R that will preserve `NA` to replace `x %in% table` other than `match(x, table) > 0`, which isn't that much longer (just 7 chars!), and in most tests, leaving off the  `> 0` part won't make any difference, since 0 tests as `FALSE`, and values greater than 0 test as `TRUE`.

However, you can easily define your own infix operator, e.g.

```
`%n%` <- function(x, table) match(x, table) > 0
```

(You could even redefine `%in%`, but that would be a really bad idea, likely to confuse readers of your code in the future.)